# What is the limit of the ratio of the sum of all real numbers from 0 to 2 over the sum of all real numbers from 0 to 1.

Tags: limits, summation, real-numbers

I approached this question I made, by saying that the sum of a finite amount of numbers from a to b separated by a common change is average•(# of numbers we have). I found the formula the # of the numbers we have to be $\frac {b-a+n}{n}$, were n is the common change from one number to the other. I also found the formula of the average to be $\frac {a+b}{2}$. Using these formulas I set up the formula of the ratio and  took the limit as n approaches 0 I got the ratio to be exactly 4. Do I have justification for this, or is this complete nonsense. Why or why not.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the concept of the sum of all numbers in an interval doesn't make sense, since there are an uncountable number of them. However, your intuition is correct as shown by user2969's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tentatively agree that the solution would be 4. The $\int_0^2 x\ dx$ (which would be the sum of the reals) would be $x^2$ evaluated from 2 to 0 $(2^2 - 0^2) = 4$. Likewise, the $\int_0^1 x\ dx = 1^2 = 1$. Therefore the ratio would be $\frac{4}{1}$

Comment: The integral is $x^2/2$, not $x^2$, but since the same factor occurs in both integrals, it cancels out.

Comment: I can see how integral would be proportional to the ratio, however I don't see why we can't integrate $x^2$ from 0 to 2 and the same from 0 to 1 to get a different answer.

Comment: You're right! Late night math on the cell. Thanks!

Comment: You'll get the same answer: 4. The integral from $0$ to $2$ is $2$, and the integral from $0$ to $1$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: No you won't the integral of $x^2$ with respect to x is $x^3/3$ so you end up with $\frac {4^3}{1^3}$=64

Comment: The integral of $x^2$ no longer represents the sum of all reals. It represents the sum of the exponents of the reals. That function increases at a different (exponential) rate

Comment: Ok cool, thanks.

Comment: Marty was trying to point out that the integral of x is not x^2 but it's actually x^2 / 2. Therefore it would in fact be (2^2 / 2 ) / (1^2/2) = 4: same result

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks all, and sorry I didn't realize.

Comment: No need to apologize!